# Internet Explorer (IE) Support

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a general questions about browser support specifically with internet explorer, what tools or methods are best to determine when to stop supporting a browser?

Comment: when you don't feel like the constant maintenance and code bulging conditions needed to suit microsoft's inferiority. Or you can always just go by the last 2 versions and screw anything beyond that. Plus it sort of depends on the service. If you are building for third world, then you might still need to support IE6. Otherwise, nobody uses LT9 anymore. Even microsoft is no longer supporting anything XP based.

Comment: it is depend on your client request. if it says, we need to support IE6, then you should implement it. i suggest you to try to implement your code to the most updated browsers, the latests, and fo IE to IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looking for ways to identify which browsers you ought to support — instead, ask yourself what type of "support" you're willing to give to any particular browser. Internet Explorer is somewhat of a chimeric term; you may be referring to Internet Explorer 7 or 8, which oftens times needs a bit of TLC to perform as you'd like, or you may be referring to Internet Explorer 10 or 11, which are modern standards-compliant browsers that need next to no additional attention.

Identify what your users are using — use tools like Google Analytics to see what they're navigating to your site with. Some may be on an older versions of Internet Explorer; some may even be on an older instance of WebKit. Determine what a "base-level" of support looks like, and deliver that. For instance, don't bother trying to teach Internet Explorer 7 and 6 how to understand media queries; let them have a mobile-first layout.

Supporting all browsers is not as difficult today as it once used to be. Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all work very hard to implement a common set of standards. Writing your code in accordance with accepted and stabilized specifications should result in a web that *just works* for your users. Should you need to deliver a browser-specific touch-up for older versions of Internet Explorer, do so via Conditional Comments that serve to make the site/project usable, but not necessarily with an aim to mimic the experience delivered in a modern browser.

"Support" doesn't necessarily mean *the same experience everywhere*. It can, and probably should, mean *a functioning site everywhere*. This definition relieves you of an immense burden to do the impossible.

Caveat, I am a Program Manager on the Internet Explorer team.

Answer (score 1):

You should use analytics like google analytics to determine how many users use a particular browser. Once usage drops bellow a certain threshold you can consider dropping support.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Google Analytics to determine what types of browsers access your application, we usually check browser utilization stats.

- For instance, IE8 still has 2% market share, so we still support it
- IE7 only has 0.3%, but we had dropped it a long time ago

One Example: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp